# Document stuck in printing queue

Tags: windows-xp, printer

My sister still has Win XP. She tried to print a document on her USB printer and now it's stuck in the printing queue. I tried the following:

- Restart the computer
- Restart the printer
- Delete the entry from the printing queue
- From the printing queue choose Printer\Cancel All Documents
- Right click the print job and choose Pause

The status of the printing job now reads "Deleting - Paused - Printing".
Nothing I do seems to get rid of this stuck printing job.
What should I do?

Answer (score 10):

The advice on [this site](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2007/03/20/remove-stuck-jobs-from-the-printer-queue/) saved me more than once:

> Pull up your Run box (Windows Key+R)
>   type in cmd and hit Enter. This will
>   bring you to the MS DOS prompt. There
>   type in the following:
>
> `net stop spooler`
>
> You should get a message saying the
>   spooler stopped successfully. Now we
>   need to clean out the spool folder.
>   This is where windows keeps jobs that
>   haven’t been printed yet.
>
> Call up your Run box again (Windows
>   Key+R) and type in the following:
>
> `%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\spool\PRINTERS`
>
> This should open a new explorer
>   window. You are likely to see bunch of
>   files in there – some of which may be
>   classified as “Shockwave Objects” by
>   windows. They are actually not
>   Shockwave files but whatever. We don’t
>   care because we will be deleting them.
>   Just remove everything you can see
>   that folder and then close the window.
>   If you can’t delete some of the files,
>   it means that you didn’t stop the
>   spooler properly. Go back and try it
>   again.
>
> This deletes all the jobs on the
>   queue, so you might need to re-send
>   some of the documents that got stuck
>   there waiting. Once the folder is
>   empty go back to your DOS prompt and
>   type in:
>
> `net start spooler`
>
> Your printer queue should be clean
>   now. If it’s not, you probably did
>   something wrong.

Comment: This saved me several times, too.

Comment: Nearly 9 years later, and STILL a problem? Ridiculous! Just had to do this to Windows Server 2016 and its managed print queues.

Answer (score 2):

The usual answer for this is to go into the Windows services tab and stop then restart the printer spooler.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answers here seem valid, I solved the problem even before I read them.

My solution\workaround was after marking the printing job to delete, I disconnected the printer from the electricity, restarted the computer and then reconnected the printer to the electricity.

I guess that when the computer restarted without the printer it was able to remove the printing job from the queue.